# forms and getElementById

Tags: javascript, forms

I am having issues using getElementById in a form. I have tried several ways with no luck. I basically need the form to verify that both First Name and Last Name fields are filled in, and display a popup box with the names displayed.

Below is the code I have tried. I tried 2 different ways in my javascript and  I am not sure what I am missing.

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="">  

    <p class="FirstName">  
        <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" />  
    </p>  

    <p class="LastName">  
        <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label></p>
        <p>
        <input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName" />  
    </p>

    <p class="submit">  
        <input name="getName" type="button" id="getName" value="Get Name" onClick=”getName();" />  
    </p>  
</form>
```

```
var getName = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("FirstName").value == "" || document.getElementById("LastName").value == "") {
        return ("Please enter a first name and a last name.");
    } else {
        var FullName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        return FullName;
    }
}
```

```
function getName() {
    var FullName = document.getElementById('FirstName');
    document.getElementById('LastName');
    if (FullName.value != "") 
        alert(FullName.value)
    else 
        alert("Please enter first and last name")
}
```

Comment: Please, next time, format your code and make it easier to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first way you tried was the right one.

The problem is, you're not binding the `onclick` event to a function.

You declare the `getName` function in the `head` tag, interpreted before the `body` tag.

But you overwrite `getName` when declaring the button `input` with its `id` and `name` set to `getName`.

You can just change its id and name to `submitButton` for example. You could also move the function declaration to the end of the `body` tag, or wrap it in an `onLoad` method.

I wrapped the `getName` call in an alert to see the result (`alert(getName())`)

Check out the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zpNSv/1/

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="">  
    <p class="FirstName">  
        <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" />  
    </p>  
    <p class="LastName">  
        <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName" />  
    </p>
    <p class="submit">  
        <input name="submitButton" type="button" id="submitButton" value="Get Name" onClick="alert(getName())" />
    </p>  
 </form>
```

AND JS

```
function getName() {
    var FirstName = document.getElementById("FirstName"),
        LastName = document.getElementById("FirstName");
    if (FirstName.value == "" ||   document.getElementById("LastName").value == "")
    {
        return ("Please enter a first name and a last name.");
    }
    else
    {
        var FullName = FirstName.value + ' ' + LastName.value;
        return FullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. And thanks for that jfiddle link. I wasn't understanding submitbutton part. I kept on seeing examples of onclick  too as  onClick=”getName(); which wasn't working. Thank you again as I am learning.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at this line, you are doing nothing with the last statement

```
var FullName = document.getElementById('FirstName');  document.getElementById('LastName');
```

You have 2 getName. only one can live.

```
function getName(){
 var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
 var lastName= document.getElementById("lastName").value;

  if(firstName === "" || lastName === ""){
    alert("You need to fullfield both First Name and Last Name");
  }
}else{alert("This work.");}
```