# How to make a href act as a submit form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I have a `a href` setup as a simple form submit, but I wanted to use it as the same type of method as  a submit on a form.

So the way I have it setup is:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a onclick="subForm('login');" style="cursor: pointer;"> login </a>

// JavaScript
function subForm(el) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  elem.submit();
}
```

Now when I click on that link it does act as if I have clicked submit on a form, I can set up a `input type=hidden` for the form so I can see it in PHP but..

I needed for this login system to not be empty and didn't want to use the older method with `if empty` then display an error after processed, so I wanted the submit button to be able to do the **same as clicking submit on a form when one of the inputs are set to `required` in their markup tag..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work assuming that that

```
<a onclick="subForm('login');" style="cursor: pointor;"> login </a>
```

is inside a form that has an id of 'login';

A couple of things you might want to know is that cursor:pointor is wrong, it should be cursor:pointer. However, if you change your code slightly then you won't need the inline style anyway. Something like this would be a good improvement in my opinion. I've not tested it but it should work:

```
<form id="login" action="/wherever/you/want/this/form/to/post/to" method="post">
    <a id="js-submit-form" href=""> login </a>
</form>

<script>
    var formToSubmit = document.getDocumentById('login'),
    button = document.getElementById('js-submit-form'),
    submitForm = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this will stop the browser trying to use the href value
        formToSubmit.submit();
    };

    button.addEventListener("click",submitForm);

</script>
```

I've just read the rest of your question but I don't actually understand what you're asking. Why wouldn't you just use the 'required' tag and some server-side validation?

Comment: Sorry I mis spelt the pointer :P Thanks for showing me, just adding this to my code to see if it works.

Comment: I guess Ill just do some server side validation, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make a [JavaScript Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) of the form fields.

[This may help you as well related to what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864606/forms-and-getelementbyid)